# PHP if condition for adding and removing without completely rebuilding

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm creating a PostgreSQL table column management tool to quickly add, remove and rearrange columns in tables. Thus far it is working great in simple scenarios where I simply append a column to the end or remove an existing column. Each of my `if` conditions call other functions to *append* a new column, *delete* an existing column or to rebuild the table as a whole; these functions work great as far as I can currently test.

How do I create an `if` condition where I'll call both the *append* function *and* the *delete* function *instead* of the rebuild function?

I have several arrays to help me determine the logic though I'm having trouble getting it worked out. Here are the arrays of column names and again in this scenario I should *not* be calling the *rebuild* function, need to call the *append* function *and* the *delete* function.

In this scenario all I'm going to do is delete the column `id_2` and add the column `id_4` so there is no need to rearrange the order or columns.

**$columns_db** - The columns as they exist in the PostgreSQL database.

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => id_1
    [2] => id_2
    [3] => id_3
)
```

**$columns_updated** - The columns in the database that we're going to keep.

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => id_2
    [2] => id_3
)
```

**$columns_submitted** - The final way the columns *should* appear when all is done,

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => id_2
    [2] => id_3
    [3] => id_4
)
```

**$columns_slice**

```
$columns_slice = array_slice($columns_submitted,0,(count($columns_updated) - 1),true);

Array
(
    [0] => id
    [1] => id_2
)
```

**$columns_remove** - The column(s) that will be dropped.

```
Array
(
    [1] => id_1
)
```

**$columns_append** - The column(s) that will be created.

```
Array
(
    [id_4] => bigint
)
```

Comment: What is a scenario where you would rebuild?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Rebuild is when a new column is inserted in any position other than the right-most / last position. The rebuild function works perfectly, I just don't want to always call it.

Comment: @Sonny Out sick for a whole week, just now getting back in to the swing of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally prefer straight forward `if` / `else if` conditions though it seemed that it would be simply too wildly convoluted to maintain. @AbraCadaver had the good sense to keep the add/remove detection separate which I adapted (would have up-voted if it wasn't deleted). I've tested about a dozen tricky combinations and haven't been able to find any false-positives. Here is the debug version I used to help visualize the logic:

```
$rebuild = 0;
foreach ($columns_append as $k1 => $v1)
{
 //echo '<div class="clear">k1 = '.$k1.'</div>';
 if (in_array($k1,$columns_slice)) {$rebuild = 1; break;}
 else
 {
  $columns_submitted_key = array_search($k1,$columns_submitted);
  //echo '<div class="clear">columns_submitted_key: '.$columns_submitted_key.', $columns_updated count = '.count($columns_updated).'</div>';
  if ($columns_submitted_key<count($columns_updated)) {$rebuild = 1; break;}//echo '<div class="error">Yeah, rebuild here.</div>';
 }
}

if ($rebuild>0) {echo '<div class="clear">1, rebuild.</div>';}
else
{
 if (count($columns_append)>0) {echo '<div class="clear">2,append</div>';}
 if (count($columns_remove)>0) {echo '<div class="clear">3,delete</div>';}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Perform column deletions first
2. `implode` column list after deletions (`$before = implode($columns_updated);`)
3. `implode` column list after additions (`$after = implode($columns_submitted)`)
4. `if (strpos($after, $before) === 0) { /* the additions are at the end */ }`

Make sure you [use the `===` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues).

As a one-liner:

```
$rebuild = (strpos(implode($columns_submitted), implode($columns_updated)) !== 0);
```